# Kivy application building apk-file not possible?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

i try to build an apk-file using buildozer -
(i created a seperate file with the py-file called main.py, buildozer.spec - i ran the building under Ubuntu)

but when i run:

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

i get the following error after running the command
(it works for sometime but at the end i get this error-message and the apk is not created)

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=testKivy --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.2.dev0,pillow --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/mnt/c/TEMPKIVY/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'Rapid1898'
#     PWD = '/mnt/c/TEMPKIVY'
#     LOGNAME = 'rapid1898'
#     MOTD_SHOWN = 'update-motd'
#     HOME = '/home/rapid1898'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/10_interop'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'rapid1898'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/rapid1898/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/rapid1898/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Oculus/Support/oculus-runtime:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common '
 'Files/Intel/Shared '
 'Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Calibre2/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common '
 'Files/Autodesk Shared/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/MySQL/MySQL Shell '
 '8.0/bin/:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/PyCharm '
 '2019.3.3/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA '
 '2019.3.4/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/mnt/c/tools/dart-sdk/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/bin:/mnt/c/flutter/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft '
 'VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/heroku/bin:/mnt/c/xampp/php:/mnt/c/Users/Polzi/AppData/Local/Markdown '
 'Monster:/snap/bin')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     OLDPWD = '/mnt/c'
#     _ = '/home/rapid1898/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/rapid1898/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/rapid1898/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/rapid1898/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

This is the file i want to convert:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (800,230)

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class LblTxt(BoxLayout):
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    theTxt = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('simpleForm.kv')
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Why is buidling the apk-file not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

Looking at the log, there's not much info, but I can assume from it that you were using WSL or something similar on Windows, not using an actual Ubuntu device. The reason why `buildozer` doesn't work, I don't know, the log doesn't go far back enough for me to find out, but it is very likely that is because WSL is not a full-fledged Linux distribution

#### The Solution

The solution for me was to use an online virtual machine called [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com)

Press cancel to the popup to open a new notebook

Initialize the VM by pressing *Connect* in the top-right part of the page

Then add a new *Code Cell* by pressing *+Code*

To set up buildozer and other commands, paste into the cell and press the play icon

```sh
!pip install buildozer
!pip install cython==0.29.19
!apt install -y \
    python3-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev
!apt install -y \
    libgstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
!apt install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6
!apt install libffi-dev
!pip install kivy
!apt install ldd
```

Then upload your files to the files page

Make another cell and run `!buildozer init`

Refresh the files screen by right-clicking and going to refresh

Open and edit the `buildozer.spec` file as you wish

Finally, make a new cell and run `!buildozer -v android debug` and wait for it to complete, *you may need to accept a few licenses on the way*

When done, refresh the file page again and then navigate to the bin directory that should now appear, press on the three dots of your apk, and press download